# Pull down to refresh data in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, list, uirefreshcontrol, swiftui

i have used simple listing of data using `List`. I would like to add pull down to refresh functionality but i am not sure which is the best possible approach.

Pull down to refresh view will only be visible when user tries to pull down from the very first index same like we did in `UITableView` with `UIRefreshControl` in `UIKit`

Here is simple code for listing data in `SwiftUI`.

```
struct CategoryHome: View {
    var categories: [String: [Landmark]] {
        .init(
            grouping: landmarkData,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted().identified(by: \.self)) { key in
                    Text(key)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest PullDownButton should be used for this but it doesn't look to be implemented at this moment

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I needed the same thing for an app I'm playing around with, and it looks like the SwiftUI API does not include a refresh control capability for `ScrollView`s at this time.

Over time, the API will develop and rectify these sorts of situations, but the general fallback for missing functionality in SwiftUI will always be implementing a struct that implements `UIViewRepresentable`. Here's a quick and dirty one for `UIScrollView` with a refresh control.

```
struct LegacyScrollView : UIViewRepresentable {
    // any data state, if needed

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView {
        let control = UIScrollView()
        control.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        control.refreshControl?.addTarget(context.coordinator, action:
            #selector(Coordinator.handleRefreshControl),
                                          for: .valueChanged)

        // Simply to give some content to see in the app
        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 30))
        label.text = "Scroll View Content"
        control.addSubview(label)

        return control
    }


    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        // code to update scroll view from view state, if needed
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject {
        var control: LegacyScrollView

        init(_ control: LegacyScrollView) {
            self.control = control
        }

        @objc func handleRefreshControl(sender: UIRefreshControl) {
            // handle the refresh event

            sender.endRefreshing()
        }
    }
}
```

But of course, you can't use any SwiftUI components in your scroll view without wrapping them in a `UIHostingController` and dropping them in `makeUIView`, rather than putting them in a `LegacyScrollView() { // views here }`.

Answer (score 44):

here is a **simple**, **small** and **pure** SwiftUI solution i made in order to add pull to refresh functionality to a ScrollView.

```
struct PullToRefresh: View {
    
    var coordinateSpaceName: String
    var onRefresh: ()->Void
    
    @State var needRefresh: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if (geo.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).midY > 50) {
                Spacer()
                    .onAppear {
                        needRefresh = true
                    }
            } else if (geo.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).maxY < 10) {
                Spacer()
                    .onAppear {
                        if needRefresh {
                            needRefresh = false
                            onRefresh()
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                if needRefresh {
                    ProgressView()
                } else {
                    Text("⬇️")
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.padding(.top, -50)
    }
}
```

To use it it's simple, just add it at the top of your ScrollView and give it the coordinate space of the ScrollView :

```
ScrollView {
    PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
        // do your stuff when pulled
    }
    
    Text("Some view...")
}.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
```

Comment: Good simple implementation but does not work when you have a URLSession data task where the background thread (task.resume()) returns immediately and the UI update kicks in after the data is fetched from the session and is getting updated with the results. The progress control ends quickly while the UI is still updating making the app unresponsive during the update. App updates after a few seconds and during that time the ProgressView is not visible

Comment: You saved me several hours of unnecessary headache with this little gem, thank you!

Comment: Nice solution but doesn't // do your stuff when pulled get called (1) when the view loads and again (2) when pulled?  Wouldn't we want it to only execute for (2)?

Comment: I'm not seeing the second onAppear be called, or the ProgressView disappear, unless I change the test to maxY < 55.  That makes that onAppear fires immediately upon loading as well.  It's not hard to work around the extra onAppear, but the maxY threshold doesn't seem to be working as expected

Comment: @GarySabo It does for me, too. I added a simply counter to avoid the first call but it feels to me too hackish (potentially unreliable) to do it so.

Comment: It is a nice implementation but there is one thing I don't like: when the user scrolls up by swiping in the list, a refresh is triggered when scrolling hits the top of the page. That's not what the user really wanted. It should be possible to improve this, though, making it perfect.

Comment: You bloody legend, this is 
I get from other posters that there are some concerns, but I did not notice any issues in testing and it is very readable and clear. love it! 

Answer (score 23):

from iOS 15+

```
NavigationView {
    List(1..<100) { row in
     Text("Row \(row)")
    }
    .refreshable {
         print("write your pull to refresh logic here")
    }
}
```

for more details: [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/refreshable(action:)?changes=latest_minor)

Comment: Would that work with `ForEach` in say a LazyVGrid? If not, what’s the best way to get pull down refresh to work on a LazyVGrid?

Comment: .refreshable *only* works with List in iOS 15, hopefully in later releases we get more support.

Comment: This only works with Lists at the moment, no use for Scrollviews...

Comment: This now works for ScrollViews as of iOS 16. It's not in the release notes but I just verified that it works.

Comment: `refreshable` does not work at all on watchOS for some reason (undocumented).

Answer (score 19):

Here's an implementation that introspects the view hierarchy and adds a proper `UIRefreshControl` to a SwiftUI List's table view: https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUIRefresh

Bulk of the introspection logic can be found here: https://github.com/timbersoftware/SwiftUIRefresh/blob/15d9deed3fec66e2c0f6fd1fd4fe966142a891db/Sources/PullToRefresh.swift#L39-L73

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution. A bit hacky, but should be easy enough to fix shall a future SwiftUI update break it.

Answer (score 11):

I have tried many different solutions but nothing worked well enough for my case.
`GeometryReader` based solutions had bad performance for a complex layout.

Here is a pure SwiftUI 2.0 View that seems to work well, does not decrease scrolling performance with constant state updates and does not use any UIKit hacks:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct PullToRefreshView: View
{
    private static let minRefreshTimeInterval = TimeInterval(0.2)
    private static let triggerHeight = CGFloat(100)
    private static let indicatorHeight = CGFloat(100)
    private static let fullHeight = triggerHeight + indicatorHeight
    
    let backgroundColor: Color
    let foregroundColor: Color
    let isEnabled: Bool
    let onRefresh: () -> Void
    
    @State private var isRefreshIndicatorVisible = false
    @State private var refreshStartTime: Date? = nil
    
    init(bg: Color = .white, fg: Color = .black, isEnabled: Bool = true, onRefresh: @escaping () -> Void)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = bg
        self.foregroundColor = fg
        self.isEnabled = isEnabled
        self.onRefresh = onRefresh
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(spacing: 0)
        {
            LazyVStack(spacing: 0)
            {
                Color.clear
                    .frame(height: Self.triggerHeight)
                    .onAppear
                    {
                        if isEnabled
                        {
                            withAnimation
                            {
                                isRefreshIndicatorVisible = true
                            }
                            refreshStartTime = Date()
                        }
                    }
                    .onDisappear
                    {
                        if isEnabled, isRefreshIndicatorVisible, let diff = refreshStartTime?.distance(to: Date()), diff > Self.minRefreshTimeInterval
                        {
                            onRefresh()
                        }
                        withAnimation
                        {
                            isRefreshIndicatorVisible = false
                        }
                        refreshStartTime = nil
                    }
            }
            .frame(height: Self.triggerHeight)
            
            indicator
                .frame(height: Self.indicatorHeight)
        }
        .background(backgroundColor)
        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
        .frame(height: Self.fullHeight)
        .padding(.top, -Self.fullHeight)
    }
    
    private var indicator: some View
    {
        ProgressView()
            .progressViewStyle(CircularProgressViewStyle(tint: foregroundColor))
            .opacity(isRefreshIndicatorVisible ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
```

It uses a `LazyVStack` with negative padding to call `onAppear` and `onDisappear` on a trigger view `Color.clear` when it enters or leaves the screen bounds.

Refresh is triggered if the time between the trigger view appearing and disappearing is greater than `minRefreshTimeInterval` to allow the `ScrollView` to bounce without triggering a refresh.

To use it add `PullToRefreshView` to the top of the `ScrollView`:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RefreshableScrollableContent: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        ScrollView
        {
            VStack(spacing: 0)
            {
                PullToRefreshView { print("refreshing") }
                
                // ScrollView content
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/tkashkin/e5f6b65b255b25269d718350c024f550

Answer (score 6):

Hi check out this library I made: https://github.com/AppPear/SwiftUI-PullToRefresh

You can implement it by one line of code:

```swift
struct CategoryHome: View {
    var categories: [String: [Landmark]] {
        .init(
            grouping: landmarkData,
            by: { $0.category.rawValue }
        )
    }

    var body: some View {
        RefreshableNavigationView(title: "Featured", action:{
           // your refresh action
        }){
                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted().identified(by: \.self)) { key in
                    Text(key)
                    Divider() // !!! this is important to add cell separation
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks great, but I can't import your package through the Swift Package Manager. Would you mind adding a Package.swift manifest to the repo?

Comment: @michasaurus this “library” holds in one file. So just copy it and you’re done

Answer (score 3):

**For iOS 16+**

You don't need to implement your custom refreshable view anymore.

Now SwiftUI Added the `.refreshable` modifier to `ScrollView`.

Just use it the way you do with `List`

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVStack {
        // Loop and add View
    }
}
.refreshable {
    refreshLogic()
}
```

Comment: You should note that this is for iOS 16+ and point to documentation if you can find it (I could not, but I did verify it works)

Comment: @walkingbrad It is for iOS 15+. "point to documentation" this is not mandatory. OP answered the question and explained it quite well.

Comment: Refreshable on ScrollView is available on iOS 16+.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest none of the top-rated answers really worked well for my scenario. The scenario had switching between the `ScrollView` and a custom `LoadingView`. And every time I switched from the `LoadingView` to the `ScrollView` which is created using the legacy `UIScrollView` using `UIViewRepresentable` the `contentSize` gets messed up.

So as a solution, I have created a library so that this might be useful for all the devs out there who are trying to find a solution for such a simple problem. I've taken good bits from around the internet went through many sites and finally tweaked the solution which ended up giving me the best solution.

Steps

1. Add `SPM` https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/BBRefreshableScrollView to your project.
2. `import BBRefreshableScrollView` to the required file.
3. Update the `View`'s `body`.

```
struct CategoryHome: View {
    ...
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            BBRefreshableScrollView { completion in
                // do refreshing stuff here
            } content: {
                ForEach(categories.keys.sorted().identified(by: \.self)) { key in
                    Text(key)
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Featured"))
        }
    }
}
```

For more details, you can follow the [Readme](https://github.com/bibinjacobpulickal/BBRefreshableScrollView#readme).

Answer (score 2):

This is a pure SwiftUI approach using a ScrollView, GeometryReader and PreferenceKey
I'm able to read the scroll offset in the ScrollView and once it gets higher than a threshold I can perform an action

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct RefreshableView<Content:View>: View {
    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.content = content
        self.refreshAction = action
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ScrollView {
                content()
                    .anchorPreference(key: OffsetPreferenceKey.self, value: .top) {
                        geometry[$0].y
                    }
            }
            .onPreferenceChange(OffsetPreferenceKey.self) { offset in
                if offset > threshold {
                    refreshAction()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    private var content: () -> Content
    private var refreshAction: () -> Void
    private let threshold:CGFloat = 50.0
}

fileprivate struct OffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    static var defaultValue: CGFloat = 0
    
    static func reduce(value: inout CGFloat, nextValue: () -> CGFloat) {
        value = nextValue()
    }
}
```

This is an example of usage of RefreshableView.
The progress indicator is not included in RefreshableView, that only provides a GeometryReader and a ScrollView including the content you want to refresh. You need to provide a ProgressView or another view to show loading is in progress.
It doesn't work with List, but you can use ForEach instead and the content will scroll thanks to the ScrollView

```swift
RefreshableView(action: {
    viewModel.refreshFeed(forceReload: true)
}) {
    if viewModel.showProgressView {
        VStack {
            ProgressView()
            Text("reloading feed...")
                .font(Font.caption2)
        }
    }
    ForEach(viewModel.feed.entries) { entry in
        viewForEntry(entry)
    }
}
```

Full example can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/gualtierofrigerio/FeedReader)

Answer (score 1):

The swiftui-introspects has not supported on masOS yet, so if you are going to build a UI that works for both iOS and macOS, consider the Samu Andras library.

I forked his code, added a few enhancements, and added the ability to use without the NavigationView

Here is the sample code.

```
RefreshableList(showRefreshView: $showRefreshView, action:{
                           // Your refresh action
                            // Remember to set the showRefreshView to false
                            self.showRefreshView = false

                        }){
                            ForEach(self.numbers, id: \.self){ number in
                                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                                    Text("\(number)")
                                    Divider()
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

For more details, you can visit the link below.
https://github.com/phuhuynh2411/SwiftUI-PullToRefresh

Comment: Loading indicator is gone when I pull for the 2nd time

Answer (score 1):

what about this

```
import SwiftUI

public struct FreshScrollView<Content>: View where Content : View{
    private let content: () -> Content
    private let action: () -> Void
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content:  @escaping () -> Content, action: @escaping ()-> Void){
        self.content = content
        self.action = action
    }
    
    @State var startY: Double = 10000
    
    public var body: some View{
        ScrollView{
            GeometryReader{ geometry in
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    if geometry.frame(in: .global) .minY - startY > 30{
                        ProgressView()
                            .padding(.top, -30)
                            .animation(.easeInOut)
                            .transition(.opacity)
                            .onAppear{
                                let noti = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
                                noti.prepare()
                                noti.impactOccurred()
                                action()
                            }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                .onAppear {
                    startY = geometry.frame(in:.global).minY
                }
            }
            content()
        }
    }
}


#if DEBUG
struct FreshScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FreshScrollView {
            Text("A")
            Text("B")
            Text("C")
            Text("D")
        } action: {
            print("text")
        }

    }
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

I was pretty dissatisfied with the options for pull to refresh in SwiftUI. Even when using the introspect UIKit based solutions, there were strange behaviors and some view jumping when using navigation views. I also needed something a bit more customizable so I wrote a library. It's a (nearly) pure SwiftUI implementation of a pull to refresh control and it works on both iOS 14 and 15.

https://github.com/gh123man/SwiftUI-Refresher

It's highly customizable and supports some extra features like being able to overlay the view contents (in cases where you have a static header).

Answer (score 0):

I know original question was for the List, but here is the code for the `ScrollView` and `LazyVStack`, since sometimes list is not appropriate.

```
import SwiftUI

struct PullToRefreshSwiftUI: View {
    @Binding private var needRefresh: Bool
    private let coordinateSpaceName: String
    private let onRefresh: () -> Void
    
    init(needRefresh: Binding<Bool>, coordinateSpaceName: String, onRefresh: @escaping () -> Void) {
        self._needRefresh = needRefresh
        self.coordinateSpaceName = coordinateSpaceName
        self.onRefresh = onRefresh
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            if needRefresh {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    ProgressView()
                    Spacer()
                }
                .frame(height: 100)
            }
        }
        .background(GeometryReader {
            Color.clear.preference(key: ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self,
                                   value: $0.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).origin.y)
        })
        .onPreferenceChange(ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey.self) { offset in
            guard !needRefresh else { return }
            if abs(offset) > 50 {
                needRefresh = true
                onRefresh()
            }
        }
    }
}


struct ScrollViewOffsetPreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = CGFloat
    static var defaultValue = CGFloat.zero
    static func reduce(value: inout Value, nextValue: () -> Value) {
        value += nextValue()
    }

}
```

And here is typical usage:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var refresh: Bool = false
    @State private var itemList: [Int] = {
        var array = [Int]()
        (0..<40).forEach { value in
            array.append(value)
        }
        return array
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            PullToRefreshSwiftUI(needRefresh: $refresh,
                                 coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 3) {
                    withAnimation { refresh = false }
                }
            }
            LazyVStack {
                ForEach(itemList, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("\(item)")
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is for swiftUi its better to use pure swiftUi as @Anatoliy Kashkin  mentioned in his answer , So i've updated his answer to support enable/disable refreshing from outside and inside the view .

Create `PullToRefresh` struct View :

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct PullToRefresh: View {
    
    @Binding var isRefreshing:Bool
    var coordinateSpaceName: String
    var onRefresh: ()->Void
    
    @State var needRefresh: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if (geo.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).midY > 50) {
                Spacer()
                    .onAppear {
                        needRefresh = true
                    }
            } else if (geo.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).maxY < 10) {
                Spacer()
                    .onAppear {
                        if needRefresh {
                            needRefresh = false
                            onRefresh()
                        }
                    }
            }
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                if needRefresh || isRefreshing {
                    ProgressView()
                } else {
                    
                    Image(systemName: "arrow.clockwise")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    
                    Text("Refresh")
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }.padding(.top, isRefreshing ? 0 : -50)
    }
}
```

Now u can use it like this :

```
@State var isRefreshing:Bool = true

var body: some View {
    
   
      
            ScrollView(){
                
                PullToRefresh(isRefreshing: $isRefreshing, coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                    fetchOrders()
                }
                
                VStack(alignment : .leading){
                    Text("Some view...")
                    
                }
                
            }.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
```

By setting `isRefreshing` true , its will show the progress and set it to false when you finish ur http request or updating data etc

Answer (score 0):

I refactored @Anthony

[image]

**PullToRefreshView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

struct PullToRefreshView: View {

    // MARK: - Value
    // MARK: Public
    var coordinateSpaceName: String
    var action: () -> Void

    // MARK: Private
    @State private var ratio: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var isRefreshing: Bool = false

    private let threshold: CGFloat = 50


    // MARK: - View
    // MARK: Public
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            if proxy.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).midY > threshold {
                Spacer()
                    .onAppear {
                        isRefreshing = true
                    }
            
            } else if proxy.frame(in: .named(coordinateSpaceName)).maxY < 6 {
                Spacer()
                    .frame {
                        let x = $0.origin.y + 6
                        ratio = max(0, min(1, x / threshold))
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        guard isRefreshing else { return }
                    
                        isRefreshing = false
                        action()
                    }
            }
        
            progressView
        }
        .padding(.top, -threshold)
    }

    // MARK: Private
    private var progressView: some View {
        ZStack {
            ActivityIndicatorView(isAnimating: $isRefreshing, style: .medium)
                .scaleEffect(1.3)
                .padding(.top, 6)
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .opacity(ratio)
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct RefreshableScrollView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var previews: some View {
        let view =  ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                PullToRefreshView(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                
                }
            
            
                ForEach(0..<10) { i in
                    Text("\(i)")
                        .frame(height: 60)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                        .border(.gray)
                }
            }
        }
        .coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
    
        view
            .previewDevice("iPhone 11 pro")
            .preferredColorScheme(.light)
    }
}
#endif
```

**ActivityIndicatorView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct ActivityIndicatorView: View {

    // MARK: - Value
    // MARK: Public
    @Binding var isAnimating: Bool
    let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style
}

extension ActivityIndicatorView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
        let view = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
        view.hidesWhenStopped = false
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<ActivityIndicatorView>) {
        isAnimating ? uiView.startAnimating() : uiView.stopAnimating()
    }
}

#if DEBUG
struct ActivityIndicatorView_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {
        ActivityIndicatorView(isAnimating: .constant(true), style: .medium)
    }
}
#endif
```

**ViewExtension.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

extension View {

    func frame(perform: @escaping (CGRect) -> Void) -> some View {
        background(
            GeometryReader {
                Color.clear
                    .preference(key: FramePreferenceKey.self, value: $0.frame(in: .global))
            }
        )
        .onPreferenceChange(FramePreferenceKey.self) { value in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { perform(value) }
        }
    }
}
```

**FramePreferenceKey.swift**

```
 import SwiftUI
 
 struct FramePreferenceKey: PreferenceKey {
     
     static var defaultValue: CGRect = .zero
   
     static func reduce(value: inout CGRect, nextValue: () -> CGRect) {}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this is working for me the best using Introspect

```
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct PullToRefreshTryView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel: ViewModel = .init()

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(1...100, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text("Hemant Shrestha \(index)")
                }

            }
        }
        .introspectScrollView { scrollView in
            scrollView.refreshControl = viewModel.refreshControll

        }
    }
}

extension PullToRefreshTryView {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {

        let refreshControll: UIRefreshControl = .init()

        init() {
            refreshControll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onRefresh), for: .valueChanged)
        }

        @objc
        private func onRefresh() {
            print("value changed")
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                self.refreshControll.endRefreshing()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Link for introspect: https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect

Answer (score 0):

Based on ldiqual's SwiftUIRefresh solution, I'am did a full analog of system refresable view modifier, but works from iOS 13+

[PullToRefresh from iOS13+](https://github.com/Oleg-E-Bakharev/PullToRefresh)

Use case

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PullToRefresh

struct SimpleSample: View {
    var body: some View {
        List(0..<20) { row in
            Text("Item \(row)")
        }
        .pullRefreshable { // An iOS 15 refreshable analog
            print("custom refreshing...")
            try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
            print("done!")
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    SimpleSample()
}
```

[image: Result]