# Are SwiftUI components backed by their UI-/AppKit equivalents?

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui

As far as I know you are able to create your own wrapper around `UIKit` components (as can be seen in this [pull-to-refresh adapation for SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56545872/5516238)).

However, I was wondering whether e.g. a SwiftUI `Button` is, behind the scenes, actually backed by a `NSButton` or `UIButton` respectively?
Alas, I couldn't find anything in the offical documentation. Is there any statement by Apple on this matter?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Open the view debugger and look for yourself

Comment: Ha, that's a great idea!

Comment: So when I have a SwiftUI app the debugger simply says `Button`, while the label reads `UIButton` in a Storyboard app. So I guess this answer my question with a "no"? Was this also the case in the early days of SwiftUI or was it just a simple wrapper at some point?

Comment: Given how the controls work, assuming it's "no" for most things make sense. Some controls, like the Picker, might still be a wrapped UIPicker, but overall you should think of them as new. Aside from curiosity, there's no value to you as a programmer in knowing how it's done anyway. SwiftUI is a entirely different paradigm.

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. The tendency goes to "always no", so don't rely in perspective, but in short-term some UIKit-fallback workarounds work.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do any of you want to put that in an answer so I can accept it? I could answer and just cite you otherwise.