# Programmatically show the pull to refresh activity indicator of a refreshable List

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, pull-to-refresh, swiftui-environment

I wonder if there's a simple way to make visible the activity indicator used by the refresh control of a SwiftUI `List`? This would provide a consistent appearance of a refreshing UI, regardless of how the refresh was initiated.

After enabling pull to refresh on a `List` by using the `refreshable` modifier, the `List`s environment has its `refresh` item set, which is a `RefreshAction` used by the refresh control. My guess was that using this `RefreshAction` would maybe also trigger the visibility of the refresh control, which I tried:

```
struct MyView : View {
    @State var content: Content
    
    var body: some View {
        _MyView(content: $content)
            .refreshable { // assigning `refresh` to the environment
                await refresh()
            }
    }
    
    private func refresh() async {
        // ...
        content = newContent
        // ...
    }
}

struct _MyView : View {
    @Environment(\.refresh) private var refresh
    // [ content binding, etc... ]

    var body: some View {
        List {
            // ...
        }
        .onAppear {
            Task { await refresh?() } // doesn't show the activity indicator of the list
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work.

Since I can't find a `isRefreshing`/`refreshState` or similar property of `EnvironmentValues` I'm wondering if maybe there's another (simple) way to trigger its appearance?

Comment: There is no build in possibility to achieve this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56493660/pull-down-to-refresh-data-in-swiftui/65100922#65100922) are some answers how you could implement your own solution.